# How to redirect ssh requests in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, gitea

I'm using the gitea versioning system in a docker environment. The gitea used is a rootless type image.

The http port mapping is “8084:3000” and the ssh port mapping is “2224:2222”.

I generated the keys on my Linux host and added the generated public key to my Gitea account.

**1.Test environment**

Later I created the ssh config file `nano  /home/campos/.ssh/config` :

```
Host localhost
  HostName localhost
  User git
  Port 2224
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

After finishing the settings i created the myRepo repository and cloned it.

To perform the clone, I changed the url from `ssh://git@localhost:2224/campos/myRepo.git` to `git@localhost:/campos/myRepo.git`

To clone the repository I typed: `git clone git@localhost:/campos/myRepo.git`

This worked perfectly!

**2.Production environment**

However, when defining a reverse proxy and a domain name, it was not possible to clone the repository.

Before performing the clone, I changed the ssh configuration file:

```
Host gitea.domain.com
  HostName gitea.domain.com
  User git
  Port 2224
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then I tried to clone the repository again:

`git clone git@gitea.domain.com:/campos/myRepo.git`

A connection refused message was shown:

```
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
ssh: connect to host gitea.domain.com port 2224: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I understand the message is because by default the proxy doesn't handle ssh requests.

Searching a bit, some links say to use "stream" in Nginx.

But I still don't understand how to do this configuration. I need to continue accessing my proxy server on port 22 and redirect port 2224 of the proxy to port 2224 of the docker host.

The `gitea.conf` configuration file i use is as follows:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    server_name         gitea.domain.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.key;


    # logging
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/gitea.access.log;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/gitea.error.log warn;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.2:8084;
        include    myconfig/proxy.conf;
    }

}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name gitea.domain.com;
    return      301 https://gitea.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

**3. Redirection in Nginx**

I spent several hours trying to understand how to configure Nginx's "stream" feature. Below is what I did.

At the end of the `nginx.conf` file I added:

```
stream {
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/stream;
}
```

In the `stream` file in `conf.d`, I added the content below:

```
upstream ssh-gitea {
    server 10.0.200.39:2224;
}

server {
    listen 2224;
    proxy_pass ssh-gitea;
}
```

I tested the Nginx configuration and restart your service:

`nginx -t && systemctl restart nginx.service`

I viewed whether ports 80,443, 22 and 2224 were open on the proxy server.

`ss -tulpn`

This configuration made it possible to perform the ssh clone of a repository with a domain name.

**4. Clone with ssh correctly**

After all the settings I made, I understood that it is possible to use the original url `ssh://git@gitea.domain.com:2224/campos/myRepo.git` in the clone.

When typing the command `git clone ssh://git@gitea.domain.com:2224/campos/myRepo.git`, it is not necessary to define the `config` file in ssh.

This link helped me:

https://discourse.gitea.io/t/password-is-required-to-clone-repository-using-ssh/5006/2

Comment: nginx I'm pretty sure won't work, how I do it is change the servers general ssh port to not 22 (it shouldn't be 22 anyway), then use iptables to do the forwarding from 22 into the containers 2224 or let docker do it

Comment: Proxy server and docker server are different servers. I want to continue accessing the proxy server normally through port 22. I would like proxy port 2224 to be forwarded to Docker port 2224. Upon receiving the request on port 2224, the docker host would forward it to port 2222 of the container. But another problem is that the proxy doesn't listen on port 2224.

Comment: Exactly. The problem you have right now is that the first server (proxy) does not have anything listening on port 2224. So you need something to listen on that. A potential soln is discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/226952/i-need-a-reverse-proxy-solution-for-ssh)

Comment: I was able to configure redirection in Nginx. See the topic "3. Redirection in Nginx".

Comment: The item "4. Clone with ssh correctly". Describes how to use the original ssh url from the repository.

Answer (score -2):

In previous messages I explained my solution. So I'm setting this question as solved.